# Griffon official Tutorial: unable to successfully build griffon-swing-groovy project generated with lazybones

Tags: gradle, griffon

I am following the [Griffon official Tutorial](http://new.griffon-framework.org/tutorials/1_getting_started.html) but I cannot get it running using groovy as main language and swing as UI library.

This is my environment:

```
$ gvm version
Groovy enVironment Manager 2.4.2

$ lazybones -version
Lazybones version 0.8.1

$gradle --version
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 2.4
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2015-05-05 08:09:24 UTC
Build number: none
Revision:     5c9c3bc20ca1c281ac7972643f1e2d190f2c943c

Groovy:       2.3.10
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.4 compiled on April 29 2014
JVM:          1.8.0_45 (Oracle Corporation 25.45-b02)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.9.5 x86_64
```

The `lazybones` templates (found in `$HOME/.lazybones/templates`) are: `griffon-javafx-java-1.3.0.zip`  `griffon-swing-groovy-1.3.0.zip`    `griffon-swing-java-1.3.0.zip`.

As I would like to use groovy as main language and Swing as UI library, I ran the following command accepting all defaults:

```
$ lazybones create griffon-swing-groovy sample
```

Then `$ cd sample` and `$ gradle build`.

Unfortunately `$ gradle build` fails at `:compileGroovy` with the following errors:

```
error: SampleController does not implement griffon.core.artifact.GriffonController @griffon.metadata.ArtifactProviderFor(value=griffon.core.artifact.GriffonController.class) public class SampleController
error: SampleModel does not implement griffon.core.artifact.GriffonModel @griffon.metadata.ArtifactProviderFor(value=griffon.core.artifact.GriffonModel.class) public class SampleModel
error: SampleView does not implement griffon.core.artifact.GriffonView @griffon.metadata.ArtifactProviderFor(value=griffon.core.artifact.GriffonView.class) public class SampleView

3 errors
startup failed:
Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

1 error

:compileGroovy FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileGroovy'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

I understand the actual meaning of the errors, but I wonder if there is something wrong with my setup, or whether the Tutorial is just faulty.

Do you have any idea what's wrong and how I can fix it?

UPDATE: It seems that `gradle v2.4` changes the way annotated code is compiled causing the build to fail. The solution is to downgrade `gradle` to `v2.2.1`.
This issue is tracked on [github](https://github.com/griffon/griffon/issues/68).

For those who might be interested, you can install multiple versions of `gradle` through `gvm` as follow:

```
$ gvm install gradle 2.2.1
```

If you want to see what versions are available (and which one is currently in use) issue the following command:

```
$ gvm list gradle
```

Thanks in advance,
zxxz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downgrading to `gradle v2.2.1` allows a successful build. I updated my own question with further details.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the problem is Gradle 2.4 added APT support for Groovy source code, which breaks Jipsy/Gipsy. The workaround is to downgrade to Gradle 2.3 in the meantime.

Comment: Actually downgrading to `gradle v2.3` doesn't fix entirely the problem. In fact it compiles but the build itself fails on `:signJars`. Downgrading to `gradle v2.2.1` allowed a successful build.